# Apply model policy in a global scope query

Tags: laravel-5

I have a complexe user policy (extending the PolicyAbstract class) granting reading/editing access for a given user to other user based on several rules and other parameters of the current user.

I am currently applying the policy on each records and filtering out the user the given does not have access **after** the query has been performed by walking the collection.  This has the adverse effect of messing up the pagination collection results as I remove records after the pagination was set.

I would like to apply the policy in a global scope so the forbiden user are already filtered from the paginated collection.
Something like this:

```
public static function boot() {

    parent::boot();
            
    static::addGlobalScope('user_selection', function(Builder $builder) {
        $builder->[involve the user policy here]
    }

}
```

Is this possible in any way?
Any help or pointer to achieve it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could find a way to involve a policy in a global scope.
Had to duplicate the "read" policy rules in a Scope definition and use that to filter records before pagination.